# If $X$ represents the sides of a 6-sided die, and $Y$ represents the sides of a fair coin, what would be the value of, say, $F_{XY}(3, H)$?

Tags: probability-distributions, random-variables

If $X$ represents the sides of a 6-sided die, and $Y$ represents the sides of a fair coin, what would be the value of, say, $F_{XY}(3, H)$?

Is it $\frac{1}{2}$? Why or why not?

**Note:** To my understanding, the following is the table for $F_{XY}(x,y)$:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
    - & 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 & 5 & 6 & - \\
    T & \frac{1}{12} & \frac{2}{12} & \frac{3}{12} & \frac{4}{12} & \frac{5}{12} & \frac{6}{12} & 1  \\
    H & \frac{2}{12} & \frac{4}{12} & \frac{6}{12} & \frac{8}{12} & \frac{10}{12} & 1 & 1  \\
    - & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1 & 1  \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

Comment: What do you think does $F_{XY}(3, H)$ mean?

Comment: @callculus, edited the question.

Comment: So in your case $P(Y\leq T)=0.5$ and $P(Y\leq H)=1$, right? And if additional  $F_{XY}(x, x)$ is the cdf of $X$ and $Y$ then you´re right that $F_{XY}(3, H)=0.5$. But it could be the other way round $P(Y\leq H)=0.5$ and $P(Y\leq T)=1$. It depends on the definition what is supposed to be "bigger": head or tail.

Comment: @callculus, traditionally, $T$ is considered $0$, and $H$, $1$.

Comment: I don´t how it is traditionally defined. But if $Y=0$ represents the event that tail occurs then you´re right. But traditionally the definition of a random variable is defined in the exercise $;)$